# Why do i keep getting "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST." error on laravel 9 api?

Tags: php, laravel, backend

Im having a problem while developing an api with laravel. The problem im having is that i keep getting this error "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST." across most of my routes.

I dont know why im getting the "GET method is not supported", im not even using it. Here is the actual route:

```
Route::post('/addEvent', [SpecialEventsController::class, 'store']);
```

To try and fix it i tried switching the method from post to get and that does remove the error but it brings another one. And also the get method isnt the appropriate method so it wont work. When i tried sending requests on postman everything seemed to work fine. The problem is only when i try on a browser.

Comment: how are you sending the request on the browser as you would have to use a form or javascript to send a POST request

Comment: im just using the route url so in this case http://127.0.0.1:8000/api//addEvent.

Comment: you are using it how? just typing it into the browser?

Comment: yes just typing it in the browser, since im making it as an api i dont have a from. Is that where the problem is?

Comment: yes, that is a GET request ... unless you are submitting a form as a POST method or using javascript to make a request you will be making GET requests

Comment: ohhh alright i got it, so i guess everything is ok with the code. And i will connect it with the front end once it is finished. Thanks alot

Comment: any API request  is to get a data from database , so a api request is GET method type.
if you put the `Route::post`, it wont handle the same and return you error, for testing you can use `Route::any`. Try it once please `Route::any('/addEvent', [SpecialEventsController::class, 'store']);` . if the code runs means you have error with ony request type, all else is workning fine .

Answer (score 0):

You can't hit your post method in browser tab where you can only hit "GET" method.
"POST" method is only for submitting. While get method is used to retrive things and hit in browser URL holder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use programs like postman to Request, get results, and test the API
Or if you need lighter tools, there is an add-on for VScode (Thunder Client), which is light and does the job

[image]

This can be done using js code
But it doesn't need to be all that complicated as long as there are good testing tools